# Can you extend Abstract Java Classes from JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, javax.script

I'm working on a project that makes really heavy use of the javax.script.* packages. I have a situation where I would like to create JavaScript objects that extend an Abstract Java Class, much like you can use Invocable.getInterface to make JavaScript objects that implement Java interfaces. Is this possible? And, if so, how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to go the route of generating bytecode at runtime (using [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) as below) then no.  You can do it with interfaces using [proxy classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) but there is no equivalent for abstract classes.

If you really want to try BCEL, your best strategy is to do this:

1. Write a method that uses BCEL to generate a `byte[]` of bytecode for a new class that extends the abstract class and delegates every abstract method to JavaScript.
2. Define a naming convention that relates abstract classes to the wrapper, e.g. `foo.MyAbstractClass` corresponds to `foo.MyAbstractClassDynamicLangWrapper`.
3. Roll a `ClassLoader` that implements [findClass](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findClass%28java.lang.String%29) to recognize that naming convention and to generate the class bytes and calls [defineClass](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)
4. Make sure your scripting language uses your custom classloader to resolve class names in scripts.  I think in Rhino you use [setApplicationClassLoader](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/apidocs/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.html#setApplicationClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29) but I'm not sure.

Comment: That sounds nasty. I think I'll come up with another solution, if that's the case.

Comment: @Mike Samuel What about java to typescript. i mean vise versa. I am working on a project which is implementing some java native functions. What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: @9me, are you running javascript compiled from typescript in Rhino?

Comment: No. I have a package written in java, and using some inner java classes ie java.util.stream. And now I am re-writing that package in typescript. I am able to implement my package logic, but what about `java.util.stream` I can not implement now java class stream class at all. So my question was in my case what is the best way to do that ? I am trying to implementing few functions, but that is not enough. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can; previous poster is wrong. See the [documentation for JavaAdapter](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/scriptjava.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using the built-in stuff in the javax.script namespace which doesn't expose all of the underlying Rhino objects. My question was pretty specific to that situation, but this is still a somewhat useful answer.

Comment: Actually, this is exposed in the javascript side and should still work with javax.script

Comment: Important note: the "documentation" for JavaAdapter is a joke -- there's a paragraph on the linked page, and a few sites around the net have generated JavaDoc with literally no commentary at all. :(

Also, as Michael points out, you *can* do this -- in your Javascript code, you have to pass out `new JavaAdapter(MyJavaClass, {myOverloadedFunc: function(a,b){return a+b;})`, which you can cast to a `MyJavaClass` using `Context.jsToJava` (that one actually *has* docs).

Comment: The JavaAdapter object provided by default in JRE6+'s javax.script package _won't_ let you implement abstract classes in javascript. Only interfaces can be implemented using JavaAdapter. See [Java Scripting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsengine). Not sure I agree with this statement from Oracle...

> The uses of JavaAdapter to extend a Java class or to implement 
> multiple interfaces are very rare.

... extending Abstract classes is rare?